# Getting a string in code-behind containing the selections in a multi-select listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What I want to do is take all of the selected items from a milti-select listbox and put them in a comma separated string, so I can store it in a table.  I've searched and found code, but for some reason the qualifier is never found to be "true".  It sees every selected item as "false".  Am I processing this in the wrong order?

Here's my ASP section (cut because it's a HUGE file, but this is the important stuff):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="PBR.WebForm1" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"%>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AJAXControls" %> 

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/ui.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"> 
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
<div> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelX" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" Height="390px"  
                    Width="900px" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px">
<ContentTemplate>
    <AJAXControls:TabContainer runat="server" ID="tabContainer" Height="373" Width="900" > 
        <AJAXControls:TabPanel ID="secondTab" HeaderText="Tracking Page 2" runat="server"> 
            <ContentTemplate> 
                <div style="border:1px solid blue;">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="40px" style="margin-left: 19px" 
                    Width="860px">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="170">System/Document Change:</td>
                                <td width="30"><asp:ListBox id="ddlSysDocChg" runat="server" Width="90px" Rows="2" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox></td>
                                <td width="40"></td>
                                <td width="200">System/Document Change Completed:</td>
                                <td width="20"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkSysDocChg" runat="server" Text=" " AutoPostBack="true" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                </asp:Panel> 
                </div>
                <p></p>
                <div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate> 
        </AJAXControls:TabPanel> 
    </AJAXControls:TabContainer> 
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br /> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" 
        runat="server" /> 

</div> 

</asp:Content>
```

In my code-behind, I have this (as you can see, I've tried it 2 different ways and I believe I found both methods on this very website):

```
    protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Read the selected items from the listbox
        //string SQLCode = "";
        var selectedQuery = ddlSysDocChg.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
        string SQLCode = String.Join(",", selectedQuery).TrimEnd();

        //foreach (ListItem listitem in ddlSysDocChg.Items)
        //    {
        //        if (listitem.Selected == true)
        //        {
        //            SQLCode = SQLCode + ", " + listitem;
        //        }
        //    }

    }
```

Can anyone tell me why it always tells me there's nothing selected?

EDIT:
This is what's in my Page_Load:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
                // Check to see which tabs should be active
                LoadTabPages();
            {

```
            try
            {
                string strSQL = "SELECT ComboValue, ComboText FROM dbo.tblComboBoxes WHERE ComboName = 'ddlSysDocChg' ORDER BY ComboText ASC;";

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, str);
                DataSet DailyRun = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(DailyRun);

                ddlSysDocChg.DataSource = DailyRun;
                ddlSysDocChg.DataTextField = "ComboText";
                ddlSysDocChg.DataValueField = "ComboValue";
                ddlSysDocChg.DataBind();

                foreach (ListItem item in ddlSysDocChg.Items)
                {
                    item.Attributes.Add("Title", item.Text);
                }

                // Insert a blank row into the DropDownLists so there is no default name
                ddlSysDocChg.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the error
                Console.WriteLine("Making Call to " + ex + "");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the same happen with the 'foreach' that you've commented out?

Comment: Yes.  It just never sees listitem.Selected as "true".

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your list is in an updatepanel whose postback is 'Conditional', and the button is 'outside' the updatepanel.

Try putting it 'inside' the update panel as in this tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb399001(v=VS.100).aspx

Or alternatively, specify the button as a 'Trigger' as in the same tutorial.

Comment: I tried the trigger.  No change.  As I step through the code I can see the selected listbox items highlighted on the form, but as the code steps through each item in the listbox it's still not finding listbox.Selected to be "true" for any of them.  It does read all of the items in the listbox, it just doesn't think any are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you databind the `ListBox` also postbacks? Check the [`IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack) DataBindListBox();
}
```